# How to change rounded avatar in React Native Gifted Chat

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

Currently figuring out how to change the avatar in the chat to a square with border radius. Any ideas? It's not in their documentation, or i just missed it.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `avatarStyle` prop and in `GiftedChat` component like

```
<GiftedChat
    messages={...}
    onSend={...}
    user={...}
    avatarStyle: {
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      width: 40,
      height: 40,
      borderRadius: 0, // change it to 0
  }
/>
```

`avatarStyle` default using these properties

```
avatarStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
```

Comment: This is a style not a prop?